# c and formatted output

Tags: c, string-formatting

```
char *star="*";
int space=5;

printf("%5s",star);
```

I want to give 5 spaces to my star so it should look on command line like `|     *|`

But the space quantity must be a variable so users can decide.

I tried `printf("%%ds",i,s);` not worked. Thank you.

Comment: BTW- I believe the first line should read `const char *star="*"`. Minor issue, but string literals are constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%*s", space, star);
```

or

```
printf( "%*.*s", space, space, star);
```

then you will always print max. 5 chars.

hth

Mario